# Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Tags: javascript, watin, comexception

I am using WatiN for IE automation. I want to automate Yahoo Search (just for test). When I run `WatiN.Core.Document.Eval("js code")` right after launching IE, it works and I can run my javascript on the page. However when I do some search in Yahoo and then call `WatiN.Core.Document.Eval("js code")`, it throws COMException DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND. Here is the method where the exception is occuring (WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.Expando.cs)

```
public object GetValue(string propertyName)
        {
            var property = AsExpando.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Default);
            if (property != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return property.GetValue(Object, null);
                }
                catch (COMException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Exception details:

```
Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.ExpandoViewOfDispatchEx.DispExInvoke(String pstrMemberName, Int32 MemberDispID, Int32 Flags, Binder pBinder, Object[] aArgs, ParameterModifier[] aModifiers, CultureInfo pCultureInfo, String[] astrNamedParameters)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.DispatchExMethodInfo.Invoke(Object pObj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder pBinder, Object[] aParameters, CultureInfo pCulture)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.DispatchExPropertyInfo.GetValue(Object pObj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] aIndex, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.Expando.GetValue(String propertyName) in d:\AdvancedSE\Releases\SE-Dev Rel 8.3.0.0\Source\CommonPlugins\Source\CommonPlugins\SE.Core.IEAutomation\WatiN\Core\Native\InternetExplorer\Expando.cs:line 48
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to evaluate the script after the DOM is loaded is completely?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't help. Any other ideas please ?

Comment: Are you getting ANY type of errors when the page loads and before you run your code? (check with CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome or F12 on IE)

Comment: Alas! No runtime JS error.